# Enviar POST com Ajax e CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Há quase 1 dia estou enfrentando um problema o qual até o momento só conseguir resolver (ter certeza de que estava certo) fazendo o errado, ou seja, gambiarras.

Estou tentando criar o Checkout Transparente do PagSeguro mas não consigo enviar o POST com o token do Cartão de Crédito e o "Sender Hash"...

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
                    PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId("<?php echo $sessionId ?>")                     

                    var sender_hash = PagSeguroDirectPayment.getSenderHash();

                    var card_token = PagSeguroDirectPayment.createCardToken({
                        cardNumber: "4111111111111111",
                        brand: 'visa',
                        cvv: "123",
                        expirationMonth: "12",
                        expirationYear: "2030",
                        success: function (response) {

                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });

                    $('input[name="pagar-cartao"]').click(function () {

                        event.preventDefault();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<?php echo base_url() . "donate/pay/" . $details->id?>',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: 'cc_token=' + card_token + '&sender_hash=' + sender_hash,
                            beforeSend:function(){
                                console.log("O seu pedido está sendo processado. Aguarde...");
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log("Obrigado por doar. O seu pedido foi processado com sucesso!");
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                console.log("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar os dados. Tente novamente.")
                            }

                        });


                    });


                });
```

O problema é que o controller não recebe os malditos posts.

Define no controle o seguinte, caso o $_POST["pagar_cartao"] (submit) seja enviado, ele irá recebe o $_POST['cc_token'] e $_POST['sender_hash'] (já tentei até fora do submit)

Ele pegaria os posts enviados pelo Ajax. É o que deveria acontecer, mas não acontece. Eu não consigo eviar o POST com o token do cartão e do sender_hash. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Boa tarde. Você está mandando via Http, certo?
Ao invés de utilizar `$_POST['']` tente utilizar o `$this->post('');` Tive esse mesmo problema quando implementei um RestFull com o Codeigniter.